# Preprocess property during deserialization

Tags: php, symfony, serialization

Let say I have the following class:

```php
final class Foo
{
    public string $bar;
}
```

The following data

```json
{
    "bar": "SGVsbG8gd29ybGQ="
}
```

And the follwoing symfony/serializer:

```php
return new Serializer(
    [
        new ArrayDenormalizer(),
        new ObjectNormalizer(
            propertyTypeExtractor: new PropertyInfoExtractor(
                typeExtractors: [
                    new ReflectionExtractor()
                ]
            )
        )
    ],
    [new JsonEncoder()]
);
```

When deserializing the data, an object with the correct data is created.

```php
$object = $serializer->deserialize('{"bar": "SGVsbG8gd29ybGQ="}', Foo::class, 'json');
```

`$object` is of type `Foo` and the property `$bar` contains `"SGVsbG8gd29ybGQ="`.

I would like to "preprocess" the property `$bar` and decode (base64) the property and instead of having the raw value, I would like to have `"Hello world"`.
I tried using the context of a custom denormalizer, but had no success.
Is there any way for achieving this?

Many thanks.
Regards.

Comment: Why do you want to do that in the "preprocess" phase instead of after got the object?

Comment: Because the `$bar` property may contain binary data and that the JSON object sent to me is base64 encoded. I would like to have the ready-to-use binary value in the serialized object

Comment: You can deserialize it, decode $bar and re-serialize it

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not look very efficient to me

Comment: Really? And what does efficient to you? And have you tried it regardless, does it work at least (without being efficient)?

Comment: Maybe it works. I have not tried this way and I found something better than multiple serializations/deserializations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a simple and effective solution: use a normalizer which re-executes the normalization afterwards. To be sure that the decoding is not performed multiple times, a value in the context is added.

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Exception\BadMethodCallException;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DenormalizerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DenormalizerAwareTrait;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DenormalizerInterface;

final class FooDenormalizer implements DenormalizerInterface, DenormalizerAwareInterface
{
    use DenormalizerAwareTrait;

    private const ALREADY_CALLED = 'FOO_PREPROCESS_ALREADY_CALLED';


    public function denormalize(mixed $data, string $type, string $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        if ($this->denormalizer === null) {
            throw new BadMethodCallException('Please set a denormalizer before calling denormalize()!');
        }

        $data['bar'] = base64_decode($data['bar']);
        $context[self::ALREADY_CALLED] = true;

        return $this->denormalizer->denormalize($data, $type, $format, $context);
    }

    public function supportsDenormalization(mixed $data, string $type, string $format = null, array $context = []): bool
    {
        if ($context[self::ALREADY_CALLED] ?? false) {
            return false;
        }

        return $type === Foo::class;
    }
}
```

This custom normalizer is added to the list:

```php
return new Serializer(
    [
        new FooDenormalizer(),
        new ArrayDenormalizer(),
        new ObjectNormalizer(
            propertyTypeExtractor: new PropertyInfoExtractor(
                typeExtractors: [
                    new ReflectionExtractor()
                ]
            )
        )
    ],
    [new JsonEncoder()]
);
```

When the deserialization is done, the normalizer will be called twice:

- The first time the value is decoded
- The second time it is skipped because the context contains `self::ALREADY_CALLED` with the value `true`